# How to annotate a Django QuerySet with a Point?

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have a model A that has fields lat(FloatField) and lon(FloatField). I want to annotate the QuerySet using a point:

```
A.objects.annotate(point = Value(Point(F('lat'), F('lon')), output_field=PointField()))
```

I keep on getting `TypeError('Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.')`

For some reason Django is not recognizing the fields and instead is passing them as strings (I think).

How do I accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I tried using F() as well but its still giving the same error. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @bryan60 doesn't work due to field type compatibility. Maybe it's because I'm using mysql5.7.

After testing multiple ways I got it right. This works for me ;)

env: django3.2, mysql5.7

```py
A.objects.annotate(
    position=Func(
        F('longitude'), 
        F('latitude'),
        function='POINT',
        template="%(function)s(%(expressions)s)",
        output_field=PointField(srid=4326)
    ),
    distance=Distance('position', location)
).order_by('distance')
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally believe you're better off writing a one time migration to add the point field rather than annotating this, but you are just passing strings ATM. You need to use `F`

```
A.objects.annotate(
    point=ExpressionWrapper(
        Point(F('lat'), F('lon')), output_field=PointField()))
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations